# finished with non-zero exit value 1 in new project

Tags: android, gradle

I just setup all my android setup on 64 bit system in which installed API level 21 and 19 also after setup every thing every time when I tried to create a fresh project whether its  for API 21 or for 19 all failed with non zero exit value

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1



C:\Users\rahul\IdeaProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
```

Comment: Please, in the question itself. Use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32158388/edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the appcompat v21.

You have to compile your project with api21.
In your `build.gradle` change:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    //...
}
```

If you are switching to appcompat 23, you have to use API23.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    //...
}
```

Comment: yeah i got the answer changed in api 23

Comment: Mark the answer if it resolves your issue. It can help other users.

Answer (score 0):

I am phased these kind of error...

**MUST REMEMBER**

Your ***compileSdkVersion*** must match the ***support library's major version.***

> > Since you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.

OR

> > Alternatively you can continue compiling against version 22 of the Android SDK by switching to the latest support library v22.

if, you need to set ***compileSdkVersion*** to ***23***.

Since API 23 Android removed the deprecated Apache Http packages, so if you use them for server requests, you'll need to add useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' to build.gradle as stated in [Apache HTTP Client Removal](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client):

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
        ...

        //only if you use Apache packages
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    dependencies {
         //only if you use Appcompat dependencies
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
     }
```